# how to retrieve polymorphic relations and how model structure should be

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have 3 models called Customer,Receiver and Legal. Each model can have only one card and I have created a Model called Card.

this is my cards table in database

```
id | cardable_id | cardable_type | number               |  ...
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |  1          |   Receiver    | 6221-0612-0410-4907  |  ...
2  |  5          |   Customer    | 6301-4569-7896-4563  |  ...
3  |  2          |   Legal       | 6748-8520-4569-9630  |  ...
```

My Card Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Card extends Model
{
    public function cardable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

My Customer Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    public function card()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Card::class,'cardable');
    }

}
```

My Legal Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Legal extends Model
{
    public function card()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Card::class,'cardable');
    }
}
```

And My Receiver Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Receiver extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function card()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Card::class,'cardable');
    }
}
```

In my routs in web.php for testing relations I wrote the code below:

```
Route::get('test',function () {
  $card = \App\Card::find(1);
  return $card->cardable;
});
```

and I faced following error:

> Class 'Receiver' Not found.

And when I try to use inverse relation:

```
Route::get('test2',function () {
  $customer = \App\Customer::find(5); // a customer with id=5 does exist
  return $customer->card;
});
```

it returns null.
I'm trying to get an instance of card's owner using `$card->cardable` and also get an instance of card using `$customer->card` or `$receiver->card` or `$legal->card`
What am I missing? Is this the right relation I have chosen for my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cardable_type` must be link to model like `\App\Receiver`

Comment: Your answer is correct, I thought app folder is considered as root folder for this purpose.
Is there a way to change root folder for relations?

Comment: @AliSeyfi no, you must manually point current location of model.